# FFMPEG merge one audio and one video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to get this to work for a few hours and am having no luck.  I have two .mp4 files - one is audio and one is video.  All I want to do is merge them into one file so the audio and video play together.  I know I am close but I keep getting stuck on "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_hstack_0".

My command I am using is:

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -y -i .\camera.mp4 -i .\screen.mp4 -filter_complex hstack output.mp4
```

Output of each file type is attached.

Thank you for your help - we found a bug in a screen recording app on our AMD laptops and this will helps us with a temporary fix.  I work at a tech college and we are scrambling to get online videos going for the students to learn remotely.
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB4WS.png)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSZ9P.png)

Comment: I think this is answered on [superuser.com "How to merge audio and video file in ffmpeg"](https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg).

Comment: I played with the commands in that post and it worked! 

./ffmpeg -i screen.mp4 -i camera.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental output.mp4

Comment: @KarlR No need for `-strict experimental`: it hasn't been needed for AAC encoding since 2015.